# No bootable device after changing UEFI to Legacy

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, bootable-media

I'm using an ASUS aspire e 15 laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed. I wanted to boot from a live USB, but no matter what, it boot even though, the same live USB works on another machine.

Boot order was set to

1. USB
2. Linux
3. HDD

When I turned the PC on, I had `security boot fail` message.
I cannot change `Secure boot` to `disabled` because it is grayed out.

Now comes the part where I probably messed up.

I have read somewhere that I should change boot mode from `UEFI` to `Legacy`, so I did. I turned the PC on and all I had was black screen with a white horizontal blinking input line. I turned pc off again, entered into bios and changed boot mode back to `UEFI`.
Now when I turn the PC on, I get `no bootable device` message.

When I go to the boot menu, the only option I can see is USB, no more HDD available. When I unplug the USB, the list becomes empty.

In BIOS, boot priority order now misses Linus but I see HDD on first place like always.

At this point I'm too scared to go further myself. I erased both my systems with important files and projects. Can someone please help me and if possible, explain to me what I did wrong? I'm complete newb to these things.

Comment: Why did you erase your files?  You can get a USB to SATA adapter and plug the device into another computer to access your files, had you not erased them.  Maybe data recovery software depending on how you erased the files.

Answer (score 0):

If everything you have actually done is simply switching from UEFI to Legacy and viceversa, this is really odd.

It looks like you are mostly worried about whether you lost your data or not. To ensure that everything is ok (as it should be), try booting from your live USB. You can then check the contents of your hard drive from there.

Some research on the internet tells me that in order to disable Secure Boot you need to first set up a supervisor password in your UEFI firmware. 
That could help in booting the live USB.
You usually find the options to set up a password and disable Secure Boot in the *Security* tab in your UEFI.

Comment: You are right, I'm mostly worried about data. I managed to boot live usb when I switched to Legacy. I have never used it before but I couldn't boot from usb while on UEFI, which is odd because I did it in past without problems. Checked my files and both windows ans linux files are undamaged, but I still cannot boot from HDD, still same black screen with blinking dash on Legacy and "no bootable device" on UEFI along with no HDD at all on boot menu(but present in boot priority list in bios).

Comment: I suggest that you make a backup of all your files on a physically separated device before attempting any kind of troubleshooting. Try doing that while I let my mind think about what might be causing this. By "boot menu" you mean GRUB?

Comment: By boot menu I mean menu that appears when I press f12. GRUB is completely out of picture right now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There should be a setting to restore BIOS to default settings somewhere. I would try that before anything else.

Also, a live boot drive may be UEFI compatible or Legacy compatible and sometimes not both, so it may only work in UEFI mode and your secure boot is not trusting it, in which case you will have to take steps to disable it (if you know you can trust the USB!!)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this, but you can go into the BIOS settings at startup and click 'Advanced Boot Options' and check the box for "Enable Legacy Options ROMs". Apply and exit, go back in and switch to Legacy boot.  Then restart. Should boot the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Xiaomi Mi Air 13.3 2018. Switched from `UEFI` to `Legacy`, then back, got `No bootable device`.
The reason is UEFI dropped NVRAM boot entry (maybe all, idk) when you switch to `Legacy`. So, you need to add one manually after switch back from `Legacy` to `UEFI`.
First you need to enter UEFI Shell. More info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), I just show what I did for Arch Linux:

```
map
```

displays list of device mappings. I found fs1 is my boot partition, simply by listing files on that partition:

```
ls fs1:
```

and further

```
ls fs1:\EFI\arch
```

found grubx64.efi - boot loader

```
bcfg boot dump
```

list of existing boot entries. I removed them, because it was some useless `Network boot` and `CD/DVD boot` (wut? I have no CD/DVD on my noteboot), so drop them:

```
bcfg boot rm 0
```

repeat until you see no boot entries

```
bcfg boot add 0 fs1:\EFI\arch\grubx64.efi
```

and

```
exit
```

or just reboot.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once. If you still have the boot medium from when you installed Linux (I'm guessing it didn't come with the PC), you can chroot into your Linux partition and reconfigure grub. See https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=GRUB/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader

If you don't want to do that, there might be another way. Try to get into the BIOS and add a boot option. It's easier with some BIOS's than others. Try to add /EFI/<your linux distro>/grubx64.efi from the main disk and boot from that. I think the Windows boot manager is /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi, but I don't know for sure.